# Get user specified long date format in UWP

Tags: c#, date, uwp, date-formatting

I want to convert a date to the user set long date format. The Current Culture is en-US, but the user is able to set a long date format of his/her choice in Control panel -> Region -> Long Date.

In this case, here I set the Format to Hungarian, and selected the yyyy. MMMM d. format (keeping the Current Culture in en-US).

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern returns an incorrect pattern.

So does the Windows.​Globalization API.

In my Package.appxmanifest:

```
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
```

Anyone knows how to get the date format from control panel -> region -> long date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the UWP API's don't expose the Regional Settings; having said that I did find a [working solution](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2015/11/02/cultureinfo-changes-in-uwp/) a while back, though I haven't tested it with Creators Update so can't confirm if it still works!

**Update:** I've found [a non-hacky way](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2017/05/03/cultureinfo-changes-in-uwp-part-2/) of doing this, using the [GetLocaleInfoEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103.aspx) Win32 API.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that did manage to get the "HU" culture. But, said culture has two long date formats, and CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern returns the default (which might not be the same the user selected in Control Panel).

Comment: Actually, it seems like in new DateTimeFormatter("longdate", new[] { "US" }).Patterns[0], the correct pattern gets shown, which is selected. Thanks again, it was an interesting read!

Comment: I've updated this with more information, and a better way to retrieve the "proper" CurrentCulture!